# Error in FACET API in drupal when integrating it with Solr

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, faceted-search

```
Notice: Undefined index: #active in FacetapiFacetProcessor->processHierarchy() (line 1562 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/adapter.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #active in FacetapiFacetProcessor->processQueryStrings() (line 1603 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/adapter.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #active in FacetapiFacetProcessor->processQueryStrings() (line 1604 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/adapter.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #markup in facetapi_sort_display() (line 381 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #markup in facetapi_sort_display() (line 381 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #markup in facetapi_sort_display() (line 381 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget.inc).
Warning: uasort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function in FacetapiWidget->applySorts() (line 305 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #active in FacetapiWidgetLinks->setThemeHooks() (line 68 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget_links.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #markup in FacetapiWidgetLinks->buildListItems() (line 102 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget_links.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #html in FacetapiWidgetLinks->buildListItems() (line 107 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget_links.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #active in FacetapiWidgetLinks->buildListItems() (line 137 of /srv/bindings/cda094ccdab94690bf13ccc53186f1f5/code/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/widget_links.inc).
```

I am getting the above error for the facet api, this error is not coming for all the items which are indexed it is coming only for few items

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed by making changes to the adapter.inc file in the facetapi as mentioned in the link https://drupal.org/node/1398036.